# Redshift jdbc driver getdate() returns time in server time zone instead of in UTC

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, jdbc, amazon-redshift

The java code mentioned below was working fine with Redshift jdbc driver 1.2. But, now seeing erroneous behaviour with Redshift jdbc driver 2.1. Can anyone confirm whether a workaround is possible in this java code or whether this is a bug in the driver 2.1 itself?

#### Information about Java code

- In a timestamp data-typed column, the value is inserted using "getdate()".
- It is supposed to add time in UTC (without timezone information).
- How the insert query is written:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
...
Connection connection = ...
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sampleTable (tsColumn, ...) VALUES (getdate(), ...)");
...
pstmt.execute();
```

#### jdbc driver 1.2.41.1065 inserts correct date in UTC

- With JDBC 4.2–compatible driver 1.2.41.1065 : https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.41.1065/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.41.1065.jar : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#jdbc-previous-versions : The query inserts the value in UTC : "2022-04-18 12:38:25"
- It is correct as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html .

#### jdbc driver 2.1.0.5 insertes date in PDT (server time zone) INCORRECT

- With JDBC 4.2–compatible driver version 2.1 (without the AWS SDK) : https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/2.1.0.5/redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.5.jar : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/jdbc20-download-driver.html, the value inserted is "2022-04-18 05:38:25".
- It is in PDT without timezone information.
- It is automatically converting the UTC time to PDT timezone where the java code is running. It is incorrect.
- Expected: The value inserted should be UTC time.

#### Workaround attempted

- Attempted to modify getdate() part in the query as follows but it didn't work:

```
convert_timezone('UTC', getdate())
```

#### Questions

- Is this a bug in the driver 2.1?
- Is there any workaround/configuration/code-fix possible in the java code explained above?

#### Related

- First posted on AWS community: https://repost.aws/questions/QUzxhtdeEJSqKlrnHMilbIew/redshift-jdbc-driver-getdate-returns-time-in-server-time-zone-instead-of-in-utc .

Comment: Are you using the Redshift Data Client to perform CRUD operations on the Redshift table? https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshift/RedshiftClient.html

Comment: The documentation of GETDATE says _"GETDATE returns the current date and time in the **current session time zone**"_ (emphasis mine). It sounds like your expectations are wrong.

Comment: @smac2020, we are NOT using RedshiftClient (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshift/RedshiftClient.html). The code is written using java.sql.Connection, java.sql.PreparedStatement, and then java.sql.PreparedStatement.execute() . But the connection deals with the Redshift.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkRotteveel. With your comment, I realized that it is indeed using the current session time zone.